# Error importing a github Android project to Android Studio

Tags: android, github

I cannot import this Github project to my Android Studio,even though My Android studio is completely up to date and I have also got the additional files(plugins,extensions,etc) required to run the project on  my Android Studio.I have also got git installed in my computer.
***The Github project=***https://github.com/C-Aniruddh/ACEMusicPlayer
*The problems faced by me are as follows*
**1.the project runs but I don't get any design view on  android studio**

Answer (score 0):

remove only 1 line from te .gradle file:

```
     defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mikheallopez.circularimageview"   <---- remove this line
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Hey I am a beginner and I am really stuck in my learning process(not making any progress).can I ping you my problems please?If yes My email id subha736121@gmail.com

Comment: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Image:Android_studio_top_level_gradle_build_file2.png

Comment: I did remove the application id from every library project(showed error for each),the gradle did build but the layout files do not render (http://i.imgur.com/Hlmel2W.png?1-main activity layout       http://i.imgur.com/9tWYNf0.png?1-project structure )

Comment: I did remove the application id from every library project(showed error for each),the gradle did build but the layout files do not render (i.imgur.com/Hlmel2W.png?1-main activity layout i.imgur.com/9tWYNf0.png?1-project structure )